# restriction maps of the constant presheaf are necessarily identity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I'm reviewing my basic sheaf theory and the following question came up:

Let $F$ be an abelian group, $X$ a topological space, and let $\mathbb{F}$ be a presheaf of abelian groups on $X$ such that $\mathbb{F}(U) = F$ for all open subsets $U \subset X$. Does it follow that $\mathbb{F}(U \to V) = \mathrm{id} : F \to F$ for all $V \subset U$?

So far I've explored by considering the triple $\emptyset \subset U \subset X$ where $U$ is an arbitrary open subset of $X$, and considering the composition $\mathbb{F}(U \to \emptyset) \circ \mathbb{F}(X \to U) = \mathbb{F}(X \to \emptyset)$, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, have you tried working from the other direction and seeing what happens if you try to construct a counterexample?

Comment: See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668409/example-of-non-isomorphic-sheaves-with-isomorphic-stalks-at-every-point for instance.

Comment: So does the following counterexample work?: $X = \{0,1\}$ with the topology $\emptyset \subset \{0\} \subset X$, $F = \mathbb{Z}$. The maps are given by $X \to \{0\}$ goes to multiplication by 2, $\{0\} \to \emptyset$ goes to multiplication by 2, and $X \to \emptyset$ goes to multiplication by 4.